# Series of conditionals in function not working properly

Tags: python

I have a really simple program to remove the first level of brackets in a string, but it seems not be working. There seems to be a problem with my logic but I can't spot it.

Given a string like `AB(CCDC)((EF)G)H`, I ought to return `ABCCDC(EF)GH`. But for some reason my program returns `ABCCDC((EF))GH`. Here is the program:

```
def removeBrackets(string):
    level = 0
    list1 = list(string)
    poses = []
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        print level, list1[i]
        if level == 0 and list1[i] == '(':
            print "skipping!"
            level += 1
            continue
        elif level > 0 and list1[i] == '(':
            poses.append(list1[i])
            level += 1
        elif level == 1 and list1[i] == ')':
            print "skipping!"
            level -= 1
            continue
        elif level > 0 and list1[i] == ')':
            poses.append(list1[i])
            level -= 1
        print "adding " + list1[i] + "!"
        poses.append(list1[i])
    result = ""
    for i in poses:
        result += i
    return result
```

As far as printing out `skipping!` and `adding!`, it performs as expected. but it still adds two brackets that it shouldn't. Please help.

Comment: "I have a really simple program to remove the *first level of brackets* in a string." Isn't it doing exactly that?

Comment: Thank you Signal, but what it returns is "ABCCDC((EF))GH" whereas what it should be return is "ABCCDC(EF)GH".

Comment: I see my mistake now, I have a poses.append(list1[i]) at the bottom of the for loop which adds the some brackets a second time. Problem solved

Comment: It's not performing as expected if it's not doing what you want. There must be something wrong with the logic of algorithm it implements (or tries to implement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    elif level > 0 and list1[i] == '(':
        poses.append(list1[i])
        level += 1

    ...

    elif level > 0 and list1[i] == ')':
        poses.append(list1[i])
        level -= 1

    ...

    print "adding " + list1[i] + "!"
    poses.append(list1[i])
```

The first two appends are redundant given the last one. They cause duplicate sets of parentheses to be added.

For what it's worth, you could simplify your function a bit.

1. `list1` isn't needed. You can work with a string the same way you'd work with a list.
2. Instead of enumerating over the indices of `string`, you could iterate over `string` directly with `for ch in string`. That gets rid of the numerous `list1[i]` lookups. (If you really do want to know the index of each character, try `for i, ch in enumerate(string)`.
3. Some redundancy is removed if you split up the character checks from the level ones. If you see a parenthesis you modify `level` either way, so best to write `level += 1` and `level -= 1` just once.
4. `poses` is an odd name for a variable. How about `parts`?
5. The last loop to create a string result can be replaced with `''.join(parts)`. This is a funny-looking, but common, Python idiom.

Result:

```
def removeBrackets(string):
    level = 0
    parts = []

    for ch in string:
        print level, ch

        if ch == '(':
            level += 1

            if level == 1:
                print "skipping!"
                continue
        elif ch == ')':
            level -= 1

            if level == 0:
                print "skipping!"
                continue

        print "adding " + ch + "!"
        parts.append(ch)

    return ''.join(parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
poses.append(list1[i])
```

this line at the bottom of the for loop adds a second bracket when the iterator is at '(' or ')' and not at level 1 or 0